# Diagonalization with orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Determine an orthogonal amtrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix, where

$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 7 & 4 & -4 \\ 4 & -8 & -1 \\ -4 & -1 & -8\end{bmatrix}$$

I found the required matrix by using eigen vector approach. But it is not orthogonal.

How to proceed to find orthogonal matrix. Please help

Comment: The key here is that the matrix $A$ is symmetric, so it is possible.  The only difficulty you would have is with eigenvectors which share the same eigenvalue, because eigenvectors for *distinct* eigenvalues are automatically orthogonal.  The other point to be careful of is *normalizing* eigenvectors to have unit length.  Then these eigenvectors (as columns) will give you the $P$ as an orthogonal matrix.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in the future.

Comment: This is only an issue when you have repeated eigenvalues. You will need to find an orthogonal basis for the corresponding eigenspace, as suggested by Siong Thye Goh. Eigenvectors that correspond to *different* eigenvalues must be orthogonal, so if that’s what you’re running into, then you’ve made an error in your computation.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Suppose you have found two eigenvectors but they are not orthogonal to each other. $\{ u_1, u_2\}$.

$$Au_1 = \lambda u_1$$

$$Au_2 = \lambda u_2$$

Let $v_1 = u_1$ and $v_2 = u_2 - \frac{v_1.u_2}{\|v_1\|^2}v_1$, then $v_2$ and $v_1$ are orthogonal to each other.

To make them orthonormal, divide by their length.

You might want to check out [Gram-Schmidt process.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)